# Electron cookies Error: Failed to get cookie domain

Tags: visual-studio, cookies, electron, session-cookies

im new to electron and im trying to set cookies in my login page, but for some reason im getting an error.
If this error is about setting the domain, then how do I set the domain value?
Im using localhost and oracle database.

This is the error

```
'Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to get cookie domain'
```

In my loginPage.js

```
let remote = require('electron').remote;
let cName = "mName";//cookies name
session.defaultSession.cookies.set({name: cName ,value: row[0]},//row[0] is from the database
err => {
    if(err) console.log("error:"+err);
});
```

Also, this app is going to be a offline app.
Hoping to get some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to Electron's documentation, when calling set method to set a cookie, url to associate the cookie with has to be set otherwise the promise gets rejected. In your case, domain has also to be set. Try to set domain as 'localhost'
[Electron's Cookies Set Method Documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/cookies#cookiessetdetails)